# Bicycle speakers

Tags: accessories

Hey I am looking for a pair of speakers to mount to my bike. How I plan to mount these speakers has yet too be determined, but I have tried once in the past, where I added a pair of speakers to the back-rack of my bike w/ velcro tape. The problem was that the speakers frequently fell off, and what is more, the auvio portable speakers I bought blew out quickly. So the crux of my question is: 
1) are there any speakers made for bikes that I could buy on the internet
2) if not, are there any portable speakers that would be good for my bike

Minor Details: I have a 3700 Trek mountain bike

Comment: Duplicate here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/60231/

Comment: That question was posted 5 years after this post?

Comment: On the internet, past, present and future all exist as one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time) - explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cJO3sHm7-s

Answer (score 3):

Get some boombot Rex Speakers, they sell an optional bar mount. You can use them wireless as well. They are not super cheap, but it's a nice product. You can put it on your bag as well.

http://store.boombotix.com/collections/boombot-rex-wireless-speakers

A budget option would be CycleTunes from Biologic, they strap on to your stem (assuming you have the space). It's not wireless, but you can put an mp3 player or something inside of the case.

http://www.thinkbiologic.com/products/cycletunes-speakers

Comment: Is there significant sound distortion on the rex speakers? How is the quality overall. I read a review and it did say the volume was impressive, which is a definite plus.

Comment: I've only seen this in person a few times, my friend who has one has said mostly positive things about it.  There are a dearth of reviews at the apple store though, might be a good place to check, but it does have a solid 5 star rating.  http://store.apple.com/us/product/HC659LL/A/boombot-rex-ultraportable-speaker-by-boombotix

Answer (score 2):

I know people who use [speakers like this](http://www.amazon.ca/Multi-Function-Bicycle-Speaker-External-Controls/dp/B009PAEE58/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394564925&sr=8-1&keywords=bike+speaker). They work well, and don't fall off the bike. You can hook up your existing MP3 player using the headphone jack. If you do that, the controls on speaker don't work.  Or you can plug in a USB key and play mp3 files off there, and in this case the controls on the speaker work fine.